# Installing plugman ... Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR jdeveloper

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I have just started developing with Oracle MAF and created a mobile app project as per the tutorial. When I tried to deploy it to device, get the following issue and it fails. Any directions, resolutions & help, appreciated.

```
[11:29:51 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[11:29:51 AM] Target platform is  (Android).
[11:29:51 AM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "Application1" to Android using profile "Android1".
[11:29:57 AM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[11:30:02 AM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[11:30:02 AM] Verifying a single Android device is online and connected to the ADB server...
[11:30:02 AM] Unable to obtain the version of ARM supported by the Android device.  The application may not work correctly if the device does not support at least ARMv6.
[11:30:02 AM] Cordova Plugman could not be found and needs to be installed.
[11:30:02 AM] This one-time installation may take a few minutes.
[11:30:02 AM] Installing Cordova Plugman...
[11:30:04 AM] Command-line executed: [/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java, -jar, /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/maf-helper.jar, installTools, -tools, /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools]
[11:30:04 AM] Creating directory /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/plugman
[11:30:04 AM] Installing plugman ...
[11:30:04 AM] Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR
[11:30:04 AM] /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/npm: 2: exec: /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/node: not found
[11:30:04 AM] oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[11:30:04 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.installTools(Unknown Source)
[11:30:04 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.MafHelperMain.main(Unknown Source)
[11:30:04 AM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[11:30:04 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.runProcess(Unknown Source)
[11:30:04 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.executeCmd(Unknown Source)
[11:30:04 AM] ... 2 more
[11:30:04 AM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[11:30:04 AM] ... 4 more
[11:30:04 AM] Caused by: java.lang.Exception
[11:30:04 AM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException.<init>(Unknown Source)
[11:30:04 AM] ... 4 more
[11:30:04 AM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[11:30:04 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:30:04 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[11:30:04 AM] An error occurred installing plugman. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.common.deployers.plugins.PlugmanInstallerDeployer)
```

Comment: Are you opening the JDeveloper as administrator? As I found, this kind of issue occurs when you were deploying JDev in admin user and run it in another user. If so, please open as admin user and let plugman install (this is one time installation process) later you can use it in other user account.

Comment: For development it is free, but if you want to submit it on PlayStore then "yes" you need to get license. Comment your question to https://community.oracle.com/message/12581264#12581264 this chain link, they will answer you.

Comment: You are nothing deal with module wise, everything is per app with per user and per app with unlimited user. Better contact Oracle marketing team, they are the right person to answer all your questions.

Comment: i install jdev with command  $chmod 777 jstudio11116install.bin

Comment: and open it with following command from terminal /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/./jdev.exe

Comment: i am not using adminstartor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109297/discussion-between-yogesh-doke-and-wanna-coffee).

Comment: till now no solution please help

Answer (score 0):

I spent about a day trying to find a solution to this problem. 
Turns out that the culprit is compatibility issue of the *node executable(.../Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/node)* that comes alongside jdeveloper with the OS. The official release of jdeveloper consists of a 32 bit(x86) release of node. So if you experienced this problem you may be using a 64 bit OS.

To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu system, you have to add the i386 architecture and install the three library packages libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or below, use this:

```
 echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Then enter:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```